# Dual Boot on HDD and SSD

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows, ssd

So I am dual booting windows and ubuntu on my laptop which only has an HDD and I want to get and SSD and only put ubuntu on the SSD and keep windows on the HDD any tutorials on how to do that ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Someone will have to confirm this, but during the install, Ubuntu will detect windows and ask if you want it to be removed or do a dual boot. If you select the dual boot option, and proceed to install ubuntu on the ssd, grub will automatically link the windows entry to wherever it is (in your case, the HDD) and the ubuntu entry to wherever it is (the SSD) so you shouldn't have any special setup to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, you don't need to start Windows again. You just need to **move your Ubuntu install** to the SSD.

0. Make an Ubuntu backup
1. Install Ubuntu normally, but at the Partitioner...

   1. Use the *Something else* option.
   2. Make an Ext4 partition on the SSD, if you're using UEFI instead, make two partitions on the SSD, one 100MB FAT32, and another Ext4 that takes up the rest of the space.
   3. Set the Ext4 partition as root, if you're using UEFI, set the FAT32 one as the EFI partition. This allows you to use Ubuntu on virtually any computer.
   4. Install the bootloader, GRUB to the Ext4 partition.
2. Continue installing.
3. At the end, if you made it, reuse the backup.